# How to match empty group with regex in flutter?

Tags: regex, dart, flutter

I have this working regex. currently I match all data between ;;

my input =>  `1;23;test X;2;`

my regex =>   `(\d+);(\d+);(\w+? \w+);(\d+);`

```
group1=1
group2=23
group3=test X
group4=2
```

My problèm is : my regex code doesn't work if I change :

"test X" by "test"
or if I have empty data like `;;`

I search to match in all this case.

thank you

Comment: Does it mean you want to match even if you have `;;;;`? Check `^(\d*);(\d*);(\w+(?: \w+)?)?;(\d*);$`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/HzNraN/1).

Comment: WOW so kick reply and exactly what I need. Yes for ;;;;, your are the man :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest using

```
^(\d*);(\d*);(\w+(?: \w+)?)?;(\d*);$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/HzNraN/1)

Basically, you need anchors to match the whole string, `*` instead of `+` to match 0+ chars, not 1+ chars, and `(...)?` to match an optional group.

**Details**

- `^` - start of string anchor
- `(\d*)` - Group 1: zero or more digits
- `;` - a `;`
- `(\d*)` - Group 2: zero or more digits
- `;` - a `;`
- `(\w+(?: \w+)?)?` - an optional Group 3: 1 or more word chars followed with an optional group matching a space and 1+ word chars
- `;` - a `;`
- `(\d*)` - Group 4: zero or more digits
- `$`  - end of string anchor